# React weird console.log not created by me

Tags: reactjs

Hi I was doing a few functions to sort values received from API and when I've done, everything was okay. But afterwhile I started to get weird console.log messages even though I don't have any in my code (deleted every one after making stuff work).
 Also I have a message that I didn't set a key attribute, even though I did. Their source is also from other component, I don't know why. Below I send an image, and code.

[image]

```
render() {
const {
  activeSurveys, CategoryList, IDList, activeCategory
} = this.state;
return (
  <div className="section" id="Surveys">
    <h1>
    Categories of surveys
    </h1>
    <h4>
    Choose one to fill and contribute!
    </h4>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        {CategoryList.map((element, index, array) => (
          <div
            key={keyIndex(array, index)[index].id} // Key creator from external library
            onClick={() => this.setActiveCategory(element)}
            className={activeCategory === element ? 'CategoryElementActive' : 'CategoryElement'}
          >
            {element}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <h3>
          Surveys to fill
        </h3>
        <div className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" />
        {activeSurveys.map((element, index, array) => (
          <div key={keyIndex(array, index)[index].id}>
            {element.Topic}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

When I click on index.js:22, it takes me to file from react-key-index library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index: 
[image]

I've found out that the problem is with creating a key for the second list. It's probably due to its content. First one is activeSurveys array, the second one is CategoryList
[image: First one is activeSurveys array, the second one is CategoryList]

PS. I'm new to React, so if I do something wrong in general I would be grateful for any corrections.

EDIT: Problem is solved. There was already an unique ID property in activeSurveys array, therefore keyIndex function was not only useless, but probably had to create a key under differently named property. Thanks for all help!

Comment: Could you share your `keyIndex` function? For console.logs, if you click on the `index.js:22` in the debugger, does it take you to the file with a console.log?

Comment: As I put in the comment keyIndex is from external library so I don't know its body, here's the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index.

Comment: And indeed it took me to index.js file from also this library, I'll put a screenshot in the question

Comment: It means that there's an extra console.log call in the react-key-index library you're using. Post a bug report to their tracker. The error message is a separate, unrelated issue.

Comment: The problem is not that you didn't add a key - the message says that each item should have a *unique* key.  In general, you are able to use the index as the key as long as you're not going to change the items in the array. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for an explanation. I'd look at another library, or use something unique from `element` to generate your key - you can use *anything* that is unique about the items.

Comment: JJJ thanks, I'll let them know

Comment: And David, I checked it by console.log, and in fact it creates unique keys. Also what I found is wrong, is that in the second list this library returns undefined, thus the error is thrown

Comment: You don't have to use globally unique keys, but unique for/between childs of that node, it's enought to use index from map arguments, just `key={index}`.

Comment: @xadm when we have multi map in one component maybe your answer set some key to different elements. and maybe get bugs or not?

Comment: These maps returns nodes attached to different divs, I'm preety sure it's enought uniqeness, no collisions.

Comment: @xadm you're right, but either way I need this ID later when redirecting to another path, so I think I can use it here.

Comment: pass/use it as `id` property?

Comment: @xadm I don't understand the question, can you elaborate?

Comment: not a question, hint rather ;)

Answer (score -1):

For use `react-key-index` you must use this code: `arr = keyIndex(arr, 1);`

this code add and id for simple array and add _objName for other arrays.

**be careful in simple array:**

```
['val1','val2']
```

changed t

```
[
  {
    id: 'kRf6c2fY',
    value: 'val1'
  },
  {
    id: 'lYf5cGfM',
    value: 'val2'
  }
]
```

So use this code:

```
render() {
const {
  activeSurveys, CategoryList, IDList, activeCategory
} = this.state;
CategoryList = keyIndex(CategoryList, 1); // *****
activeSurveys = keyIndex(activeSurveys, 1); // *****
return (
  <div className="section" id="Surveys">
    <h1>
    Categories of surveys
    </h1>
    <h4>
    Choose one to fill and contribute!
    </h4>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        {CategoryList.map((element, index, array) => (
          <div
            key={element.id} // id added by keyIndex()
            onClick={() => this.setActiveCategory(element.value)} // use element.value !!!
            className={activeCategory === element.value ? 'CategoryElementActive' : 'CategoryElement'}
          >
            {element.value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <h3>
          Surveys to fill
        </h3>
        <div className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" />
        {activeSurveys.map((element, index, array) => (
          <div key={element._Topic}> // _Topic added by keyIndex()
            {element.Topic}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: It produced more errors, unfortunately. And although I see the point of the first replacement you did, how does second work? Why element._Topic?

Comment: Could you paste the contents of `CategoryList` in your question?

Comment: Sure, I've just noticed that this could indeed be a problem

Comment: And the problem lies actually in activeSurveys array, but I'll put both either way

Comment: @SlawekWozniak sorry. check now again. i forget `element.value`

Comment: @SlawekWozniak so do i remove answer?

Comment: @mortezaataiy Leave it, maybe it will help someone in the future with his problem :)

Comment: @SlawekWozniak so please get me a vote. its -1 now :(

Comment: It didn't help me and I'm not sure if it's a correct answer, why would I do that?